# Why am I still getting Windows 7 updates after the End of Support date?

Tags: windows-7

I'm running a Windows 7 Pro machine in order to support some legacy products.  I haven't bought the Extended Support Updates but I've had the following updates after the end of life date (14th January)

15/‎01/‎2020:

- 2020-01 Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2,
  4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4535102)
- 2020-01 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 for x64-based
  Systems (KB4534310)
- Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - January 2020 (KB890830)

16/‎01/‎2020:

- 2020-01 Servicing Stack Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB4536952)

I wasn't expecting anything after the 14th.  Why are these updates being made available?

Comment: KB4536952 is the final update for W7 for non ESU customers

Comment: The ones you got would have happened on Jan 14 or Jan 15 if you updated a day later. The servicing stack update came after the main updates were completed. I have a Windows 7 virtual machine here and it updated as I noted above

Comment: You got exactly all the updates you were supposed to. There probably won't be coming any new ones.

Answer (score 11):

> I wasn't expecting anything after the 14th. Why are these updates being made available?

All the updates you received were released before Windows 7 ended on January 14th 2020.

- *KB4536952* was released on January 13th 2020.
- *KB4535102* and *KB890830* was released on January 9th 2020.

These dates are based on the dates that appear in the Windows Update Catalog.